# Import monaco editor using require js

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

I have installed monaco-editor using

```
npm install monaco-editor
```

now I want to require in my js file

so I have tried to require using

```
var monaco = require('monaco-editor');
```

but it is giving me **module not found error.**

Is there wrong I am doing?

Comment: There's a discussion on getting it working with front-end module loaders [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/18#issuecomment-231788869) (the short answer - it's a massive pain).

Comment: Was this resolved when using require.js and bundling? I have not been able to find a solution which does not leave monaco undefined even though the monaco editor module is executed.

Answer (score 4):

Monaco-editor uses a custom AMD style module loader. the loader.js will result in the global require being set to Monaco-editor's loader.

The [samples](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/samples/nwjs-amd/index.html) GitHub has many examples of using the editor in different contexts.

Check out how they solve your problem in the Electorn samples index.html. After persisting the Monaco-editor custom loader you would use it like in most of the examples out there. It is an AMD style loader so the syntax differs from node `var me = require('monaco')` . I am not sure if it is possible to use like node loader but after loading loader.js and persisting the require to some variable such as amdRequire you will use such as:

```
amdRequire(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () 
{ 
    // your code using monaco ns here
    monaco.editor.create( document.getElementById('elementId'), {} );
})
```

Answer (score 4):

They just released ESM distribution which is compatible with webpack etc. Check out the docs [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/master/docs/integrate-esm.md).

Also there are many examples for using monaco with [webpack](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-samples/tree/master/browser-esm-webpack), [parcel](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-samples/tree/master/browser-esm-parcel) an so on. [See all.](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor-samples)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I'm trying to load Monaco Editor in nw.js app which had require.js.

Usually Monaco Editor examples recommends using its 'Loader.js'. But if you already have another amd loader *(ex: require.js)*, then you don't need to include & use Monaco's Loader.js. By this [Github comment](https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/797#issuecomment-379764641) I got to know the Monaco's Loader.js will not do anything if it detects another amd loader.

This [official sample](https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/blob/main/samples/browser-amd-requirejs/index.html) might be useful.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>Monaco Editor Sample - Loading with requirejs</h2>
        <div id="container" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; border: 1px solid grey"></div>

        <script
            src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/require.js/2.3.5/require.min.js"
            integrity="sha256-0SGl1PJNDyJwcV5T+weg2zpEMrh7xvlwO4oXgvZCeZk="
            crossorigin="anonymous"
        ></script>
        <script>
            require.config({ paths: { vs: '../node_modules/monaco-editor/min/vs' } });

            require(['vs/editor/editor.main'], function () {
                var editor = monaco.editor.create(document.getElementById('container'), {
                    value: ['function x() {', '\tconsole.log("Hello world!");', '}'].join('\n'),
                    language: 'javascript'
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```